# MS SQL Server SQL Group By error when using max(). Msg 164

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, max

```
SELECT part_number, 
    price, 
    (Select max(sent_to_t) AS 'T' From [CIMSDB].[dbo].[price] where sent_to_t < '06/04/2013' Group by part_number)

 FROM [CDB].[dbo].[part]PAB Inner Join [CDB].[dbo].[price] PR
    ON PA.part_id = PR.part_id
 Order By part_number
```

What I am trying to do is get a list of parts, and thier prices, for the most recent send_to_t date that is before 6/4. I am currently recieving -"Error Message

Server: Msg 164, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one
column that is not an outer reference."

Comment: That error is telling you that there's no `part_number` column in the `price` table - perhaps you meant a different column. Or perhaps you did intend to be using the column from the `part` table in the outer query - but we don't know which, because we don't have your tables or data, nor know what result you were expecting to achieve.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?

Comment: Version - 2008. That is correct, part_number is from the part table. I was trying to group it by part_numbrer so it would return a list such as  Part | Price | T  | 55 | 2.5 |2012-01-12 What I want is the last price for each part before 6/04/13.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a MAX at all (which is uncorrelated with the main query above, hence the error). Even if correlated, it would give you the most recent `send_to_t` value before some date but not the price on that date. It would simply give the most recent price with an unconnected date.

You asked (my bold)

> get a list of parts, and their prices, **for the most recent** send_to_t date that is **before** 6/4

This gives you the most recent price for a part before `06/04/2013`
Basically, a "top 1 per group" but with a date filter)

```
    SELECT
        part_number, 
        price,
        sent_to_t
    FROM
        (
        SELECT
            part_number, 
            price,
            sent_to_t,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY part_number ORDER BY sent_to_t DESC) AS rn
        FROM
            [CDB].[dbo].[part] PAB
            Inner Join
            [CDB].[dbo].[price] PR ON PAB.part_id = PR.part_id
        WHERE
            sent_to_t < '06/04/2013'
        ) X
WHERE
    X.rn = 1
ORDER BY
    part_number;
```

Note `06/04/2013` is ambiguous: is it 6th April or 4th June? You should use `yyyymmdd` for safety

Comment: It is June 4th, Thanks. Note that you called [CDB].[dbo].[part] PAB but then referred to it as PA. Once those matched it worked.